# Working with JPEG images in Java

Tags: java, jpeg, bufferedimage, pixel, dct

I am using the `BufferedImage` class to read in an image as pixels which I then use bit shifting to get their appropriate components into separate int arrays. This works OK.

I have used this reference [site](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/ccdtovcd/mpeg/DCT.java.html) to manually perform DCT functions with the pixel arrays.

Methods used: `forwardDCT()`, `quantitizeMatrix()`, `dequantitzeMatrax()`, `inverseDCT()`

which then are fed back into a resultant image array to reconstruct the JPEG file, which I then use BufferedImage's `write()` method to write the pixel data back out as the image.

This works perfectly, and I can view the image. (Even better the value I use to compress visually works).

My question is, is there a way to write the quantitize coefficients as the compressed values as a JPEG?

Because the BufferedImage write() method is used to input pixel data, rather than coefficient data?

Hope this is clear.

Thanks

Comment: I think so. The idea of the bufferedImage is to store the color model and the raster, so it's basically a big bitmap.

Comment: DCT coefficients are not colour values though, they are frequency values. But maybe you might be on the right tack, would you know how create a BufferedImage constructor with coefficient values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately the DCT calculation is just one step in the whole JPEG encoding process. A complete implementation also has to deal with quantization, Huffman encoding, and conforming with the JPEG standard.

Java effectively just gives you an interface to a JPEG encoder that lets you do useful things like save images.

The ImageWriter that ImageIO.write() uses for JPEG images depends on your system. The default ImageWriter for JPEGs will only let you change some settings that affect the quantization and encoding using the JPEGImageWriteParam class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriteParam.html).

Getting your hand-crafted DCT coefficients into a JPEG file could potentially involve writing an entire JPEG library. If you don't want to do all that work, then you could modify the source of an existing library so that it uses your DCT coefficients.

Comment: OK thanks for your reply. Sorry about my late reply. It seems complicated to just write DCT coeffs to a JPEG image. Looking at that class, I came across the JPEGImageWriteParam class which seems more relevant to the subject. But I have no idea how I could go about using these classes to save them as DCT coeff. If you do know any suggested ways, please let me know? I'll give you best answer anyway. Thanks again

Comment: The most you can do with JPEGImageWriteParam is set the [quantization tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Quantization) and [huffman tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Entropy_coding) with setEncodeTables.

Comment: ...These determine how the image is encoded and they are also needed for decoding. The JPEGImageWriteParam class is "A class describing how a stream is to be encoded." What you have is not metadata or parameters, but the actual image data in a different form than the encoder expects. So this class won't be useful. I can't find any class in the standard library that would help. If you could find the documentation for the actual ImageWriter class being used that may be more useful.

Comment: OK thanks. I'm using BufferedImage to read and write pixels, which I probably  should use something like ImageWriter to have more control on how to write out the data. But thanks for your help

Comment: I was guessing that you were using ImageIO.write to save your BufferedImage as a file. ImageIO.write uses a default ImageWriter class.

Answer (score 1):

Before the DCT . . .

While JPEG has no knowledge of colors, it is normal for JPEG file formats to use the YCbCr color space. If you are thinking about writing a JPEG file, you would need to do this conversion first.

After the Quantization . . .

The coefficients are run length encoded. That's a step you'd have to add. That's the most complex part of JPEG encoding.